# How to make RegEx Ungreedy in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have the following `RegEx`:

```
val boldRegex = Regex("(?<!\\\\\\\\)@(.*)(?<!\\\\\\\\)@")

val boldRange = boldRegex.find("@test@ - this is just a test for @bold@ text")
```

When I run the above code in `kotlin` it extracts two groups with the following start/end position

```
0..38
5..33
```

What I actually need is: `0..5` and `33..38`

Is there a way how to make this `ungreedy` (at last this is how I think it's called, I am using this website to test the `RegEx`: https://regex101.com/

The original `RegEx` in PHP looks like this: `/(?<!\\\\)@(.*)(?<!\\\\)@/Us`

Comment: Only by replacing `.*` with `.*?`

Comment: I already did that and did not help, I am still receiving indexes from exterior to the interior. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: No, [it works fine](https://ideone.com/HOYCzp). I am not sure your regex will work in general though, ``"(?<!\\\\\\\\)"`` = `"""(?<!\\\\)"""` means there must be no 2 backslashes before `@`, did you mean that?

Comment: Yep, you're right, much appreciate, struggling to solve this for over an hour.